# JPA - getting distinct value from one column

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence, distinct

I have an entity that has few fields. One of them is city name. Now I want to get list of all distinct cities from that table. How can I archive that. I tried using DISTINCT keyword, but it doesn't work.

I'm using Hibernate as JPA provider but I would like to get it in pure JPA Query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.city FROM MyTable t
```

Comment: Yes, but it threw an exception that there is no [id] so an object cannot be created.

Comment: This sounds like an issue with your entity.  Does it have a PK?